# Changing Radio button input selection is not working as expected, unable to figure it out

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, radio-button, forms

I have an  issues of figuring out what is wrong with my approach.
I have two check box options(radio), if one is clicked then some inputs 
 has to change as required fields, if second one is clicked then the required field of option 1 has to become not required. I wrote a script by which it's working fine.
ISSUE: is if i select the first checkbox(option1), no matter if i change the selection(to option2), the required fields of selection 1 are appearing. they are not changing to the not required fields.

Myscript:

```
document.getElementById("pharmacy-nabp-req").addEventListener('change',function(){
document.getElementById("nabp-required").required = this.checked ;
    })
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <%= f.radio_button :submitter_type, 1, checked: false, type: "checkbox", class: "form-check-label", name: "pharmacy-nabp", id: "pharmacy-nabp-req", required: true %>
        <%= label :submitter_type, 'Pharmacy(NABP Required)', class: "form-check-label"%>

    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <%= f.radio_button :submitter_type, 2, checked: false, class: "form-check-label", name: "pharmacy-nabp", id: "nabp-notrequired" %>
        <%= label :submitter_type, 'Dispensing Practitioners and Vetenrinarians(NABP Not Required)', class: "form-check-label"%>
    </div>
```

Required field HTML:

```
<div class="form-group row">
               <%= label :nabp, 'nabp', class: "col-sm-3 form-check-label pt-0"%>
                 <div class="col-sm-9">
                 <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                   <%= f.text_field :nabp, class: "col-sm-10 form-check-label", id: "nabp-required", name: "nabp-required" %>
                   <abbr class="col-sm-6">(For Pharmacies only)</abbr>
                 </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
```

APOLOGIES, if this question is obvious to answer. I tried all the available solutions from SO but didn't work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: _I have two check box options(radio)_?!! `checkbox` or `radio`

Comment: Radio. sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on a radio button only triggers the `change` event on that button, not all the other buttons in the radio group.

You should add the event listener to all the buttons in the group, and it should check whether the `pharmacy-nabp-req` button is checked.

```js
document.getElementsByName("pharmacy-nabp").forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById("nabp-required").required = document.getElementById("pharmacy-nabp-req").checked;
  })
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="pharmacy-nabp" id="pharmacy-nabp-req">
<label for="pharmacy-napp-req">Pharmacy(NABP Required)</label>
<input type="radio" name="pharmacy-nabp" id="nap-p-notrequired">
<label for="pharmacy-napp-req">Pharmacy(NABP Not Required)</label>

<div class="form-group row">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="nabp-required">(For Pharmacies only)
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: boom! Thank you so much. Finally!!